# Nokogiri prevent converting entities

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

```
def wrap(content)
  require "Nokogiri"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<div>"+content+"</div>")
  chunks = doc.at("div").traverse do |p|
    if p.is_a?(Nokogiri::XML::Text)
      input = p.content
      p.content = input.scan(/.{1,5}/).join("&shy;")
    end
  end
  doc.at("div").inner_html
end

wrap("aaaaaaaaaa")
```

gives me

```
"aaaaa&amp;shy;aaaaa"
```

instead of

```
"aaaaa&shy;aaaaa"
```

How get the second result ?

Comment: What happens if you use `&#xAD;` instead of `&shy;`?

Comment: same result, the & is encoded into &amp; and I get &amp;#xAD;

Answer (score 0):

Return

```
doc.at("div").text
```

instead of

```
doc.at("div").inner_html
```

This, however, strips all HTML from the result. If you need to retain other markup, you can probably get away with using CGI.unescapeHTML:

```
CGI.unescapeHTML(doc.at("div").inner_html)
```

Comment: In that case you can probably get away with using CGI.unescapeHTML. Updating answer

Comment: Yes, And you lost all you entities in text which should be there (if any are originally there)
I search for a transparent solution.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you're trying to do. I believe the problem is that '&shy;' gets added as encoded text, not a HTML entity. Try parsing the string into HTML fragment using `p.content = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(input.scan(/.{1,5}/).join("&shy;"))`. If it works I'll update my answer/create another. If not, I'm out of ideas.